# Split up latest commits into multiple branches

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm aware of several questions on the subject, but I didn't find any that address this situation. The trick is that I need to pull one commit out from between two others.

My repo looks like this:

```
A - B - C     <- master
          \
            D  <- devel
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
    C  <- feature1
  /
A
  \
    B - D  <- feature2
```

I know I can probably use `rebase` for this, but after a year of using Git I'm still not clear on all the jargon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Use a commit hash rather than a base branch.

Yes, I would rebase. I know that there is a quicker way to do this via "rebase onto", but I am always confused as to how to get it just right. What I would do is create the new branches with everything, then delete what you don't want.

***base commit***

The first thing you'll need is the commit hash for commit A. You'll use this for `git rebase` in the next steps.

```sh
## Copy the 6-char hex value next to commit "A"
git log --oneline
```

***feature1***

```sh
git checkout -b feature1 master
# insert the commit hash for commit A
git rebase -i $A
# in the VI editor, delete the line representing commit B, and save
```

***feature2***

```sh
git checkout -b feature2 devel
# insert the commit hash for commit A
git rebase -i $A
# in the VI editor, delete the line representing commit C, and save
```

The `-i` flag on `git rebase` instructs to perform an "interactive rebase". This is why you are presented with an editor. Read the built-in instructions to inform yourself on what all you could do in the future as needed. Aside from rebasing local commits against updates in the upstream, I use this almost every day to rename commits and combine commits into one before pushing my changes back to the upstream. It's a very powerful tool to understand and really not that complex.